# Customizing Project File to compile project and zip entire debug folder in msBuild

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

Class Library compiles into debug folder with their dependencies.How can i automate this project with this scenario:

1.Compile project

2.Delete some additional file such as .pdb in debug folder

3.Modify some aspx file in root **(Optional)**(removing `MasterPage` property in webforms)

4.Zip entire debug folder into a file with some other extension(for example: .foo) apart from usual files.

Comment: I can see zipping them up into a separate file.  But just wh@cking your pdb files?  Maybe read this: "The most important thing all developers need to know: PDB files are as important as source code! "    http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you do not need assistance with creating the `MSBuild` task to satisfy your first criteria.

To delete files and zip, try something like this:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>
<Target Name="SomeTarget">

<ItemGroup>
    <FilesToDelete Include="Path\To\Debug\*.pdb"/>
    <DebugApplicationFiles Include="Path\To\Debug\*.*"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Delete Files="@(FilesToDelete)" />

<Zip Files="@(DebugApplicationFiles)"
  WorkingDirectory="Path\To\Debug"
  ZipFileName="Where\To\Store\Zip\Foo.zip"
  ZipLevel="9" />
</Target>
```

You can obviously store any of these values ("Where\To\Store\Zip" and "Path\To\Debug") in variables defined in a `<PropertyGroup>` element, but I omitted those for brevity.

You'd have to give more details on what you mean by modifying an aspx page, but that is generally doable via MSBuild.

The zip task is available via the [msbuildtasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks) project that can be installed via nuget: `Install-Package MSBuildTasks`.

Comment: Error 1 The "Zip" task was not found. Check the following:
 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 
2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 
3.) The task is correctly declared with <UsingTask> in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" directory.

Comment: I injected your snippet in `<Target Name="AfterBuild">`

Comment: I installed it from NuGet but there is error in compile that the path of `MSBuildCommunity` is not exist

Comment: Try replacing `$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)` with the full path to where you installed msbuildtasks

Comment: Make sure the `DebugApplicationFiles` property is set appropriately and that that folder location isn't empty at the time this zip operation runs. If you have files in subdirectories under `Debug`, use  `Path\To\Debug\**\*.*`

Comment: Why `Path\To\Debug`?
What is the mean of `**` ?
I Used `ZipFileName="Plugin\Foo.zip"` and zip file created in root of my project in Plugin folder.

Comment: ** tells MSBuild to look in `Path\To\Debug` and all subdirectories.